# How to get file ownership and permissions in android

Tags: java, android

Using ls I get the following information. How to get the same from a File Object in android.
Like How to get u0_a23 name string using File Object.

```
root@android:/ # ls /proc/ -l                                                  
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 1
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 10
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:31 1069
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 11
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 12
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 13
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 14
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 2
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 25
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 26
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 27
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 28
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 29
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 290
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 292
dr-xr-xr-x system   system            2013-07-01 12:19 294
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 3
dr-xr-xr-x system   system            2013-07-01 12:19 30
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 31
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 33
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2013-07-01 12:19 34
dr-xr-xr-x radio    radio             2013-07-01 12:19 35
dr-xr-xr-x u0_a23   u0_a23            2013-07-01 12:20 357
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with some information. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Process object and execute the command. You could append the path of the File object as parameter. After that you can read the result from the InputStream.

Please comment if you need an example.

Comment: good hack, but wont fit in my case as I have to get the information in <10ms

Comment: I didn't measure the time, yet. Does it really take so long?

Comment: /proc shows list of currently executing pids. So they are already running. Moreover If I run them again I am not sure a) I can do that b) It will solve my purpose or not as now the apps owner will become the owner of newly spawned process c) Dont know how long it will take

Comment: @Manish - I believe vRallev is proposing that you execute `ls`  That shouldn't really be necessary though, as you can definitely do the same thing which ls does in your own native library.  It may even be possible to obtain this in Java, but it's not immediately obvious how, as it gets into territory which is fairly platform-specific.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 there's [Files#getOwner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getOwner%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29), otherwise the only way is, as vRallev said, with a Process.

Try a Process to see how fast is (on my device, a Galaxy S2 in DEBUG mode, takes just 40ms. Not so much I guess).

I've tried to implement a little Object FileInfo with the file information. Maybe you can find it useful. I'm not sure it will work everytime (I'm assuming that the only parameter missing could be the size and stuff like that) but it could be a start.

```
public static void test() {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    BufferedWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;
    String test = "";
    List<FileInfo> fileInfoList = new ArrayList<FileInfo>();
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -l");
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream()));
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            fileInfoList.add(createFileInfo(line.split("\\s+")));
        }
        proc.waitFor();
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long execTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println(execTime);
}

private static FileInfo createFileInfo(String... args) {
    FileInfo fi = null;
    if(args.length == 6) {
        fi = new FileInfo(args[0],args[1],args[2],args[3] +" "+ args[4],args[5]);
    } else if(args.length == 7) {
        fi = new FileInfo(args[0],args[1],args[2],args[3],args[4] +" "+ args[5],args[6]);
    }
    return fi;
}

private static class FileInfo {
    private String permissions;
    private String owner;
    private String group;
    private String size;
    private String date;
    private String fileName;

    private FileInfo(String permissions, String owner, String group, String size, String date, String fileName) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.group = group;
        this.size = size;
        this.date = date;
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    private FileInfo(String permissions, String owner, String group, String date, String fileName) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.group = group;
        this.date = date;
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can do that, that was the last measure I had in mind if nothing works :). I have one more way though through NDK but not sure it would make sense to go that extra mile

Comment: That seems too complex to me (NDK). Performance doesn't seems to bad with Process. I'm actually developing an application that requires root permission with RootTools library and the performance are pretty good. Unfortunately it's quite "unix" spcific what you (and I) are trying to do, that's why there isn't anything better than this. : )